# How to get the time between 2 actions for debug purposes

Tags: c#

```
if (xIsReady && y.Int < xDmg)
{
   xCast();
}
if (y.Int < xDmg + zDmg)
{
   zCast();
}
```

I want that when the second function activates, it calculate the time between the "zCast()" and the "xCast()" activation.

Is possible?

Comment: It's possible. There are many ways to do this. What *exactly* are you having problems with? what did you try and what were the problems?

Comment: I'm trying to learn C#, i'm really newbie. My friend told me to use Enviroment.TickCount and StopWatch, but i'm struggling to see how those 2 functions work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
if (smiteReady && mob.Health < smitedamage)
{
   stopwatch.Start();
   smite.Cast();
}
if (mob.Health < smitedamage + spelldamage)
{
   stopwatch.Stop();
   Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);
   champSpell.Cast();
}
```

So what I did was to start the timer which the first spell was cast and then stop it when the second spell is cast.

Edit: Use stopwatch instead based on peer's suggestion

Comment: Do accept the answer if it has worked so that others know that the problem has been solved. Thanks.

Comment: You should not use date time for performance measurements. It will give you incorrect measurements, a stopwatch will give you more precise timings.

Comment: thanks, have edited the code to use stopwatch instead.